# Cross platform solution for copying files after compilation

Tags: visual-studio, cross-platform, .net-core, file-copying, buildconfiguration

In a .NET Core project, I want to copy some dll's after the project has compiled. I have successfully done that with a simple xcopy operation setup in the scripts -> postcompile section of the project.json file.

I want this copy-operation to be cross-platform, so xcopy is not an option (for Mac/Linux at least). Is there a way to copy the files that works cross platform, or some way to detect the platform so I can branch out and call a cmd script when on Windows and a shell script when on Mac/Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the project.json build system, this can be done by referencing a script file without the file extension in the "scripts" section.

```
"scripts": {
  "postcompile": "copy-assets"
}
```

To support cross-plat, you need two script files in the same folder as project.json, **copy-assets.cmd** and **copy-assets.sh**. Make sure to `chmod +x` your .sh file to it can be executed.

Comment: Would the above postcompile value which is "copy-assets" (without the extension sh or cmd) automatically pick up "copy-assets.sh" on a mac and pick "copy-assets.cmd" on a windows?